# import parent "UpTitle" class in java language

Tags: java

i am beginner in java programming. i try to import the parent "Uptitle" class in chils "subfolder/Title" class. proble is that child class can not see parent class and how to import parent class ?
[image]

Comment: What do you mean it can't see? `import UpTitle;`?

Comment: UpTitle o = new UpTitle(); // in Title class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is not allowed use package statement in named folder 'src' in java

Answer (score 2):

You can't import any classes from the root of the main package.

So you need to include in a main package, for example:

```
main
   ->  Main.java
   ->  UpTitle.java
   ->  subfolder
              -> Title.java

package main.subfolder;  
import main.UpTitle;

public class Title {
   private UpTitle upTitle;
}
```